# How to find min and max of multiple y-axes in FLOT

Tags: flot

I am using FLOT to plot charts, and I am not providing max or min value for Y-axis. It is getting auto-scaled. Now I want to get the min and max value of Y-axes. The following code works for only the first y-axis, but I want it for multiple axes.

```
var min = plot.getAxes().yaxis.min;
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the `yaxes` array in the options:

```
var yaxes = plot.getOptions().yaxes;
var min = yaxes[0].min;
var max = yaxes[0].max;
for (var i = 1; i < yaxes.length; i++) {
    if (yaxes[i].min < min) {
        min = yaxes[i].min;
    }
    if (yaxes[i].max > max) {
        max = yaxes[i].max;
    }
}
```

Comment: "plot.getAxes().yaxes" is not working."plot.getAxes().yaxis" only  works.

Comment: Change `getAxes()` to `getOptions()` which gives the axes as an array (see edited answer).

Comment: getOptions() is giving "undefined", as I have not set min and max value of y-axis. It is getting autoscaled.